# Detecting when the "Thank you" message has been dismissed after IAP OSX

Tags: macos, popup, app-store, in-app-purchase

I am working on a game on OSX with In App Purchases.
I am trying to detect when the Popup that says "Thank You, Your purchase was Successful." At the end of a successful Purchase by the user.

The Problem that I am having is I need to hide the mouse and resume input on the game after this message has been dismissed, but I can't find a suitable place to do this.

How can I find out if the OK button has been pressed on this message box?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I found a fix to my problem.

I couldn't find a way to detect when an alert is shown from another Application, as all the the In App Purchase popups come from the App Store.

The fix I used was to make sure that the App Store was open before starting the transaction. This means that OS, whether or not you are in full screen, will automatically take you to the App Store. This causes the Alerts to be shown as sheets inside the App Store rather than in front of your application. Problem solved.

I open the App Store immediately before instigating the transaction by calling this line of code:

```
 [[NSApp mainWindow] makeKeyAndOrderFront:[NSApp mainWindow]];
```

Then once the transaction finishes I grab focus on my App again.